# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument PFUserResultBlock

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

[image]

Can anybody please help me figure out why I am getting this error?

Comment: maybe the same as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091919/cannot-convert-value-of-type-pfuser-nserror-void-to-expected-argument-type-p

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to this.

**Swift3**

```
  PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: self.permissions, block: {
           (user: PFUser?, error) -> Void in
```